# Problema con SELECT max() MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT vehiculo_id, max(created_at), estado 
FROM partesdiarios 
WHERE vehiculo_id = 1
GROUP BY date(created_at)
```

y una tabla donde registro movimientos de vehículos, cada vehículo puede registrar varios movimientos en un día. Necesito obtener el último estado de cada día de un vehículo pero de esta manera no logro hacerlo, si bien la consulta me devuelve el la fecha/hora de el último movimiento de cada día, con el estado no pasa lo mismo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en tu where debe ir la condicion tambien: `and created_at = max(created_at)`

Comment: no @IgmerRodriguez ya le estoy poniendo una respuesta.. el query esta mal porque mysql te deja hacer las cosas mal...

Comment: @gbianchi ok vere tu respuesta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto es un problema comun y tiene que ver con que mysql te deja hacer las cosas mal.

En cualquier otro motor de base de datos, esta consulta tiraria un error. ¿Y por que?

Porque simplemente, la db no puede procesar una consulta de ese tipo, ya que apra el campo estado, que no forma parte del group by, o de una consulta de agregacion, que fila va a traer??

Entonces, como mysql tiene un modo NO ANSI, que permite este tipo de cosas, es que no tenes el resultado que queres.

Por defecto, en sql, cuando usas un group by, los campos tienen que ser de dos tipos:

- o forman parte de la clausula group by (para saber por cuales agrupar)
- o forman parte de una funcion de agregacion (sum, count, max, etc) para saber que hacer con todas las filas que pertenecen a esa agrupacion.

Entonces, para resolver esto, tenes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT vehiculo_id, max(created_at) as maximo
FROM partesdiarios 
WHERE vehiculo_id = 1
GROUP BY date(created_at)
```

Sin el estado, porque no tenemos ninguna funcion que nos pueda devolver el ultimo estado (no existe last).

y a esta query, agregarle el estado:

```
SELECT vehiculo_id, maximo, estado 
from (
    SELECT vehiculo_id, max(created_at) maximo, estado 
    FROM partesdiarios 
    WHERE vehiculo_id = 1
    GROUP BY date(created_at)
    ) A 
inner join partesdiarios B 
    on A.vehiculo_id = B.vehiculo_id and A.maximo = B.created_at
```

Comment: una colsulta: se podria hacer un select normal (sin el max) y en where poner esa condicion? where created_at = max(created_at)

Comment: Si , con `order by create_at asc`

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez no se puede poner created_at = max(created_at).. porque ese max a que se aplica? la db no puede resolverlo, el max debe ser el resultado de un select. si podrias hacer created_at = (select max(created_at) from.... )

Comment: @CodeNoob pero en este caso no se puede usar, porque devolveria todas las fechas, y no el maximo por fecha.

Comment: `order by created_at asc group by estado`

Comment: Cierto daria el error: Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function